# 7z getting an event not found error in command line

Tags: linux, 7-zip

I am using 7zip on my centos machine and ziping a file via command line.

This is my syntax

```
7za a -t7z backup.7z public_html\ -mx0 -xr!restricted_area
```

What i'm expecting with this syntax is to backup all files in public_html folder then exclude restricted_area folder, I am not really sure if this is correct, but the problem is I am getting this error:

```
-bash: !restricted_area: event not found
```

What does this suppose to mean? And also, Is my zipping syntax correct?

Your help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The man-page actually suggests to use **!**? Odd.  ! is usually evaluated by the shell, hence the error you get.  Try escaping it.

```
7za a -t7z backup.7z public_html\ -mx0 -xr\!restricted_area
```

Comment: Yey that worked! Thanks very much! I just added a * after public_html\ Thanks again! :)

Comment: If I want to exclude other directories, should I just repeat the -xr\! and replace the 'restricted_area' into the directory that i want to exclude?

Comment: What is -mx0???

Comment: I don't get the event error and 7z still runs, but it still includes folders it shouldn't

Comment: I am using absolute paths, is that supported?